# Accessing localhost(Xamarin)

Tags: android, asp.net, xamarin, signalr

I want to implement chat in my android app using SignalR and I download this example from asp.net:
https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr
But I can't acces to it using localhost through HubConnection. I tried using my IP adress and port number but it's not working. Does anyone has experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have an Android device than localhost is the Android device itself. Every device or pc is its own localhost to begin with. So please explain your setup better.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I used IP address of my PC but it didn't work.

Comment: `but it didn't work`. That is a very bad problem description. You should try better and give relevant info.

Comment: Did you perform any basic network troubleshooting?  ie, check your firewall, verify that you can browse to your PC's IP from your device's browser, etc?

Comment: For example I have something like this: http://localhost:53457/Default.html  than I replaced the localhost with my IP address and when I try to access to it nothing happens, can't send a message

Comment: Where is your server again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your app server is IIS Express, it won´t work by default because of network restrictions or even the firewall.

First thing, as you already realized, the client needs to connect with your machine ip, not localhost. Something like `http://x.x.x.x:port/signalr`

Then you need to make sure your machine is accesible from the mobile phone or emulator: open a browser in the phone and type a known address, like `http://x.x.x.x:port/somethingThatExists`.

If that url is not available:

1. Try disabling the firewall
2. Open powershell at the machine runing IIS-Express and run this: `netsh http add urlacl url=http://{your server ip}:{port}/ user=everyone`. (if your system language is not english, for instance: spanish, change "everyone" to "todos")
3. Open the file `applicationhost.config` in your directory solution `Solution/.vs/config/applicationhost.config` and search for the application xml node. Something like `<site name="YourAppName" id="1">...</site>`. You´ll see the `localhost` binding by default. Add a new one with the actual ip: `<binding protocol="http" bindinginformation="*:port:x.x.x.x"></binding>` (make sure the ip/port are correct. i.e: `*:57457:192.168.0.57`)
4. Restart IIS Express and try again (no need to reboot the system)