# Connect Xamarin client to SignalR server

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.android, signalr

*Before you start looking for duplicates, please read till the end.*

I have two project in virtual machine:

1. ASP.NET Web Application, hosting SignalR server. Exactly [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) tutorial project.
2. Simple Xamarin.Android project, running on Intel emulator using HAXM.
3. Enviroment: On Macbook, I have VMWare vm running Windows 10. Everything (both projects) are running inside this single vm.
4. Enviroment*: In my virtual machine's settings I set **Bridged Networking Wi-Fi**, which means *"The virtual machine appears as an additional computer on the physical Ethernet network “Wi-Fi”."* So, my vm has an IP something like 10.0.1.56.

**EDIT: Also, very important hint: I've built a Xamarin.Forms project and created the same SignalR client (look at the code below) in PCL, in OnStart method. I run iOS project and it worked!**

The problem:
Can't connect from `Xamarin.Android` client to `ConnectionHub` in ASP.NET server.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. I know that I can't use *localhost*, I thought I have to use 10.0.1.56. But that didn't work.
2. Then I followed [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240185/accessing-localhostxamarin) solution. I turned off the firewall, I run the powershell command and... I failed at *3.* I added binding in `applicationhost.config` and restart the vm and macbook. Reopened everything and using browser I could connect and sent message from 10.0.1.56:64642. Again, with regular browser. I could do that from VM and even from Macbook! but then I tried from Xamarin.Android and failed..

here's the Xamarin.Android code: It's basically default app created by Visual Studio. I just changed `OnCreate` method:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        button.Click += async delegate 
        {
            button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++);
            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://10.0.1.56:64642");
            var chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
            try
            {
                // Start the connection
                await hubConnection.Start();
                // Invoke the 'UpdateNick' method on the server
                await chatHubProxy.Invoke("Send", new object[] { "TheMessage", "JohnDoe" });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Here I'm catching those exceptions... 
            }
        };
    }
```

The exception is:

```
  {System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Network is unreachable) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Network is unreachable
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000cb] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1313 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0019b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:195 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1023 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x003ce] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:379 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at AndroidApp.MainActivity+<>c__DisplayClass1_0+<<OnCreate>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x000a5] in C:\Data\Projects\SinglaRSamples\AndroidApp\AndroidApp\MainActivity.cs:36 }
```

What could be a problem? Any suggestions? Thanks for help!

Comment: `using browser I could connect` Is that the browser on the Android device/emulator? If not, try doing that... Is your Android device/emulator on the same subnet `10.0.1.255`? Check which subnet it is actually on: `adb shell ifconfig`

Comment: It seems pretty clear based on the exception stack what the error is.... `ConnectFailure (Network is unreachable)` .... i.e. WTF is going on with `http://10.0.1.56:64642` and please confirm this IP is listening on this port.  Then you have `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP)`... seems rather obvious what the problem is so ensure that you have it listening and applicable port and interface routes configured... You might try it with the VMs using NAT rather than bridge too, and consider trying with static IP addresses assigned to the VM adapters.

Comment: Thank guys! It turned out, it was a network problem on my Android emulator. I don't know why, but "LTE" was switched off, so there was no internet - and that's the reason.. ehh.. I lost 1 day because of that :/