# How do i send a string content to Dot Net Web API(Server) from Xamarin Android App(Client)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

**In Xamarin**

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
                request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:53325/Values/UploadFile?file=");
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
                request.Headers.Add("Accept","application/json");
                //HttpResponseMessage reponse = await client.PostAsync(UploadServiceBaseAddress, stringContent);
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request);
            Toast.MakeText(this, Convert.ToString(responseMessage), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }

            HttpContent content = responseMessage.Content;
            var jsonn = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**In Dot Net Web API**

```
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {

        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Values/")]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(string file)
        {
            return Json(new { status = "success"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        }
}
```

*How do i send a string contents from **Xamarin** to **Dot Net Web API** and return the **SUCCESS** message back to Xamarin*

Comment: You can not use `localhost` as that would be your Android device/emulator (unless you have port forwarded (`53325`) using adb). Use the actual IP address of your PC/server...

Comment: `http://192.168.1.15/Values/UploadFile?file=`
                         **OR**
`http://192.168.1.15:53325/Values/UploadFile?file=`

I tried checking whether the port is open or not but the port is closed(port is not listening)

so how do i give in this ?

is the code to send a string right or not ?
@SushiHangover

Comment: Do you use a simulator or a real smartphone?

Comment: @hugo I'm using emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Web API Project, you have to make sure that it is running on the IP Address of the machine as provided by the router of your network and not on your loopback ("http://localhost:53325").

You can do this by changing your `Program.cs` in your Web API Project. Here's the code for it:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace MyApi
{
        public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //UseUrls does the trick.
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseUrls("http://*:53325")
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Once your code is running on the network, you can start testing on a real Android Device. Here's the sample Web API Action ("Get method")

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class ValuesController : Controller
        {
                [HttpGet]
                public ActionResult UploadFile([FromQuery]string file)
                {
                        return new ObjectResult(new { status = "success = " + file });
                }
                [HttpGet]
                [Route("test")]
                public string Test() { return "test"; }
        }
}
```

To make sure the app will run fine, run the Web API Project, and connect Android Device to same LAN / WiFi, now goto the /api/values/test action, and you should see the "test" string. If that's working, you can proceed with the Xamarin.Android Project.

As Data Retrieval is achieved with the HttpClient class, it can be written in a portal .NET Standard Project. I wrote this sample class:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClientApp.Portable
{
    public class SendReceiveTest
    {
        public static async Task<string> Test(string data)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var uri = $"http://192.168.0.103:53325/api/values?file={data}";
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return stringData;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your activity, you can add the data retrieval to any event, as follows:

```
using Android.OS;
using ClientApp.Portable;

namespace ClientApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "ClientApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.message);
            var getDataButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.getData);

            getDataButton.Click += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                var data = await SendReceiveTest.Test("test.txt");
                textView.Text = data;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The TextView's Text will be replaced with the returned data. You can do anything with the data; set as Toast Message, parse JSON to object using Libraries like JSON.NET, etc,.

End Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank man I really mean it, I din't try it yet but I'll try and let you know mate if I have any issues.

Comment: **UseKestrel() Error :**

`WebHostBuilder does not contains a definition for UseKestrel and no extension method UseKestrel accepting a first argument of type WebHostBuilder could be found (are you missong a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I just tried it and getting this error now and i din't try the code on the Program.cs which i'm trying only now and I don't have IIS installed in my pc so it that a problem ?

Comment: I just sorted it but now it is not establishing connection between Xamarin and Web API Project but when try hitting Web API using browser it is working fine but not working when i try in Xamarin

Comment: Emulator? Or real device?

Comment: Android Emulator

Comment: I tried it with both real device and emulator. Works with the IP Address from my WiFi Router.

Comment: I'm getting HTTP error 400 - Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

[image](http://imgur.com/a/Bchiz)

Comment: Try the web api (ValuesController ) I've written, see if that works.

Comment: Published the project in a path then hosted them in IIS then it worked.
Thanks mate.

Comment: Great. Should have worked without publishing though, nevermind.

Comment: [**That Localhost & IP Address Issue still can't solve it** to view click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240185/accessing-localhostxamarin)